# Xcode 11.7 can't set LaunchImage as a Launch Screen

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, xcode11, launch-screen

I'm using Xcode 11.7 to set Launch screen for my react native app :

I created a LaunchImage and i put all launch screen sizes

[image]

I created a Launch Screen storyboard and i keep it empty

I selected my target and in the build settings tab i selected Assets Catalog Compiler and i

selected LaunchImage as Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name

[image]

I faced a problem that i can't show the splash screen when the icon is launched